# Android - how to check activity has loaded?

Tags: android, android-activity, onload

I need to perform action, when my activity is fully loaded? Does Android have something like onLoaded method for activities? Up to now, I have able to find only onLoaded method for widgets.

Thx

Comment: I believe that technically, after onCreate() completes, the activity is fully loaded. Is this not working in your case? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Activity is loading in Thread, I need to play music after is loaded. Now it play only when loading.

Comment: there is something wrong dont know where but would be better if you paste your code too.

Comment: I will post my snippet tomorrow, thanks

Comment: Why you don't play the music after that Thread finishes doing everything?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm not sure about this but having a look at the [Activity LifeCycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) I'd say you need to override either onStart() or onResume() to do what you want.

```
@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    //Your code here
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: onResume is called often called much earlier in time than the activity is actually finished loading